# Virtual Directory - Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a project folder with three different maps

- _upload
- PrintedInSpace.Admin
- PrintedInSpace.Web

In the Admin I am able to upload images, while on the web I'm able to view them. Currently I want to save the images under ~/_upload/Images, so outside the PrintedInSpace.Admin. So I created a virtual directory

[image]

Here are the paths:

[image]

And here is how it looks like in IIS:

[image]

But the problem occurs when I try to upload an image to the virtual path, it says it can't find the path. Which isn't weird because the path doesn't exist. But I did create the virtual path in IIS, so my question is, do I misunderstand the concept of virtual directories or did I do something wrong with iis or code wise?

**Code behind**:

_fiuImage.SaveAs(fullPath);

The value of fullPath is "D:\SVN\PrintedInSpaceSolution\PrintedInSpace.Admin\_upload\Images\Panda.png"

(All \ are double \ but StackOverflow removes them)

**Error**:

*"Could not find a part of the path 'D:\SVN\PrintedInSpaceSolution\PrintedInSpace.Admin_upload\Images\Panda.png'."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by going to the properties of my project > Web > Servers and check "Override application root URL".

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this may help:

> By default, IIS uses configuration from Web.config files in the
>   physical directory to which the virtual directory is mapped, as well
>   as in any child directories in that physical directory. If you do not
>   want to use Web.config files in child directories, specify false for
>   the allowSubDirConfig attribute on the virtual directory.

Source: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#About7.0

If that doesn't help, please get back to me :)

Comment: I just went to the properties of my project and clicked "Override application root URL" under Web > Servers and then it somehow fixed my error.

Comment: Ah nice, I recommend you post the answer yourself so others may find this useful. Hope the information above helped out anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fix the IIS setting for for Virtual Directory Defaults for All Sites as follows:
IIS setting for Virtual Directory Defaults for All Sites:

1-In the Connections pane, expand the server name, then click the Sites node.
2- In the server's Sites pane, click Set Web Site Defaults... in the Actions pane.
3-In the Web Site Defaults dialog box, specify your default virtual directory credentials for all Web sites, and then click OK.

see:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/virtualdirectorydefaults